# Information over a Class

Tags: java, class, annotations

I am writing for a bigger project a system that different classes registers there commands in one CommandHandler. The Commands are Classes with the Code to Execute.
My Problem: The CommandHandler needs some informations over the Classes, the name, the permissions and the usage.

I have tried already with @interfaces but this gives me always **null**. Should i do this in an other way or could i fix this?

Code: The register in the CommandHandler

```
 public void register(Class<? extends Command> c) {
    CommandInfo info = c.getAnnotation(CommandInfo.class);
    if (info == null) return;

    try {
        commands.put(info.pattern(), c.newInstance());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The @CommandInfo

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CommandInfo
 {
/**
 * The actual name of the command. Not really used anywhere.
 */
public String name();

/**
 * A regex pattern that allows minor oddities and alternatives to the
 * command name.
 */
public String pattern();

/**
 * The usage message, i.e. how the command should be used.
 */
public String usage();

/**
 * A description of what the command does.
 */
public String desc();

/**
 * The permission required to execute this command.
 */
public String permission();
}
```

And one Command:

```
public class SetPortPoint implements Command
{
    @CommandInfo(
        name = "setportpoint",
        pattern = "setportpoint|spp",
        usage = "/maa setportpoint <arena> <wavenumber>",
        desc = "set a Port point for a Arena at a given Wave",
        permission = "mobarenaaddon.porter.setportpoint"
    )   
    public boolean execute(){
        //The Code to do
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are requesting annotation on the class, but what you request is put on a method.  Either put annotation on the class itself or enumerate its methods (`getMethods()`) and query the annotation on each one separately.  Of course, what you do depends on what you want.

Also note that annotations are not inherited to subclasses.

Comment: I have found a way over Fields and Methods so that SetPortPoint have the fields name, pattern etc. and over an abstract class the methods to get them so now i have 1 Interface and 1 abstract class. So it's a little bit diferent of what you say.  Thank you